# Java in Android from one activity to another activity

Tags: java, android, xml

I am doing a Android app where I want to show the list of travels contact numbers in a separate screen when clicked on "Travels and Holidays" button. Here is the code:

### AppActivity.java

```
package com.example.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class App2Activity extends Activity {
    String number=getIntent().getStringExtra("no");
    String name=getIntent().getStringExtra("no");
    Button button;
    Context context = this;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(context,AppActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("no","yourno");
                i.putExtra("name","yourname");
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        return;
    }
}
```

### App2Activity.java

```
    package com.example.android;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class App2Activity extends Activity {
        String number=getIntent().getStringExtra("784568435,438756435,435784365");
        String name=getIntent().getStringExtra("Travels1,Travels2,Travels3");
        Button button;
        Context context = this;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main2);

            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i=new Intent(context,AppActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("number","784568435,438756435,435784365");
                    i.putExtra("name","Travels1,Travels2,Travels3");
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

            return;

        }

    }
```

### main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Travels and Holidays" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Travels and Holidays Details</string>

</resources>
```

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mkyong.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".AppActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".App2Activity" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

What I want is: When I click on "Travels and Holidays" button in the first screen, I want the travels name and contact number to be shown on another screen. When clicked on any travels, it should redirect to the call option of that number.

Where am I going wrong? Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get your intents inside the onCreate() method. Also, while getting the intent values, you're using the same key "no" both times. You're going to get the same value in both number and name. Do this instead

```
String number=getIntent().getStringExtra("no");
String name=getIntent().getStringExtra("yourname");
```

Your onCreate() method inside AppActivity should look like this

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(context,AppActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("number","784568435,438756435,435784365");
                i.putExtra("name","Travels1,Travels2,Travels3");
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        return;

    }
```

Then delete the getIntent() code, from above the onCreate() method.

Comment: I did a small change in App2Activity

Comment: Move both your getIntent() code inside of the onCreate() method.

Comment: I moved that 2 lines down of this line - setContentView(R.layout.main2); Is that right?

Comment: It's not an error, just a warning. Did you try running your app?

Comment: I am getting 2 errors for this line. "String number = getIntent().getStringExtra("784568435,438756435,435784365"); String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("Travels1,Travels2,Travels3");          Error is "The value of the local variable number is not used. The value of the local variable name is not used"

Comment: Remove those two lines. They are not required.

Comment: Done. I ran the app. But when I click on "Travels and Holidays" button, it shows "Unfortunately, Travels has stopped." and app automatically closes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78228/discussion-between-bidhan-a-and-perl-allinone).

Answer (score 0):

You should only use `getIntent()` inside `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should `getIntent()` on the Activity's onCreate() method not when initializing the Activity. Because instance variables initialization is actually put in the constructor(s) by the compiler, I think the intent was not initialized in the Constructor.

```
public class App2Activity extends Activity {
    String number;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        number = getIntent().getStringExtra("no");
    }
}
```

Comment: I did a small change in App2Activity

Answer (score 0):

In your button listener you have to call the `App2Activity`, also note a typo in context`,`App2Activity.class

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i=new Intent(context,App2Activity.class);
        //                             ↑: number 2 missing!!

        // note you're harcoding the no and name variables!
        i.putExtra("no","yourno");
        i.putExtra("name","yourname");
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

After,

- remove the similar code in `App2Activity` (is not necessary to show content)
- make a layout with `label` or `TextView` to show the info
- in `oncreate` of `App2Activity` get the extras
- put in this label or textview the extras from the intent

To get extras:

```
String no = intent.getStringExtra("no");
String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
```

Comment: I did a small change in App2Activity